# The Meaning of $ \mathbb{E} $ Operator in the Pix2Pix Loss Formula of a Neural Network / Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I've been observing the [Pix2Pix Paper - Image to Image Translation with Conditional Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004) and wondered on formulas. For example, the objective of the CGAN is:
[image],

where x - observed image, z - random noise, y - target image and G and D are generating and discriminating models respectively.

What does this `E` with "double line" stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $ \mathbb{E} \left[ \cdot \right] $ is the [Expectation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).  
In the context above it means you run over all the pairs of `x, y` and average the values.